# calculating the average of nested array in particular manner by python?

Tags: python, arrays, square

i need a way to calculate the average of the nested array ( even or odd ) in this following manner:

let's say we have this array ( list ) ( even 4*4 ) :

```
mylist = [
[1,6,5,6],
[2,5,6,8],
[7,2,8,1],
[4,4,7,3]
]
```

the output must be like this

```
mylist = [[3,6],
[4,4]
]
```

based on this calculation

```
1 + 6 + 2 + 5 / 4 = 3
5 + 6 + 6 + 8 / 4 = 6
7 + 2 + 4 + 4 / 4 = 4
8 + 1 + 7 + 3 / 4 = 4
```

the same thing if we have an odd nested array like this

```
mylist = [[7,9,1],
[4,2,1],
[3,2,3]]
```

the output would be :

```
mylist = [[5,1],
[2,3]
]
```

based in same calculation above ..

```
7 + 9 + 4 + 2 / 4 = 5
1 + 1 / 2 = 1
3 + 2 / 2 = 2
3 / 1 = 3
```

so how we can implement this process by python, notice that i know how to do the normal average for each array like just increasing the numbers for each array line by line and divided by its count ..

```
 mylist = [[70,80,90],
[30,40,50],
[0,10,20],
[10,40,40]]
avglist = []
for x in mylist:
    temp = 0
    counter = 0
    for y in x:     
        temp = temp + y
        counter = counter + 1
    avglist.append(temp/counter)
    print()
print()
print(avglist)
```

but in that problem .. i face a problem to how to jump to next array then came back to first array and so forth ....

**

> notice: it has to be a square array ( row length = column length )

**

Comment: Can you use numpy or is it a constraint to use a list?

Comment: it has to be a list ....

Comment: @pissall the problem is on the algorithm in itself not the mean .. thank u for replying

Comment: @HussamGold in your first even 4x4 example, is the calculation `1 + 6 + 5 + 6 / 4 = 3` suppose to be `(1 + 6 + 2 + 5) / 4 = 3`? Also, just to clarify, you're not actually calculating the means, but rather the floor of the mean right?

Comment: @JethroCao u r right sorry for mistake .. yeah in way to become 3 instead of decimal number

Comment: @HussamGold so do you want the precise arithmetic mean, or the floor of the mean (if for example you want the final answer to be a list of integers still)? And also, can I assume that the input list will always be NxN?

Comment: @JethroCao like if the answer is 3.5 , it has to be 3 , so yeah using floor. Also, we assuming that it's always squared 2*2 3*3 4*4 etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I present a frame challenge: instead of counting each quadrant one at a time, count all quadrants at once.

Assuming we are always computing four numbers (the sums of each quadrant, with a bias towards the top-left quadrant if the sizes are unequal), we can simply prepare them in advance, and then scan over each cell of the matrix, determine which quadrant it's in, and increment that sum:

```
def calculation(matrix):
    # prepare empty lists for each quadrant
    # we will add each element from the matrix to the list that corresponds to its quadrant
    # then at the end we will take the average of each.
    sums = {
        (True, True):   [],  # top-left
        (True, False):  [],  # top-right
        (False, True):  [],  # bottom-left
        (False, False): [],  # bottom-right
    }
    # scan over each cell by row and column index
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for col in range(len(matrix[row])):
            # use boolean checks to index into sums depending on quadrant
            sums[(row < len(matrix) / 2,      # is it in the top half?
                  col < len(matrix[row]) / 2  # is it in the left half?
                )].append(matrix[row][col])
    # calculate and return averages (using integer division instead of true division)
    return [[sum(sums[True, True])   // len(sums[True, True]),     # top-left
             sum(sums[True, False])  // len(sums[True, False])],   # top-right
            [sum(sums[False, True])  // len(sums[False, True]),    # bottom-left
             sum(sums[False, False]) // len(sums[False, False])]]  # bottom-right
```

Test cases:

```
>>> mylist = [
... [1,6,5,6],
... [2,5,6,8],
... [7,2,8,1],
... [4,4,7,3]
... ] 
>>> calculation(mylist)
[[3, 6], [4, 4]]

>>> mylist = [[7,9,1],
... [4,2,1],
... [3,2,3]]
>>> calculation(mylist)
[[5, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so here's my try. It's a bit verbose, but I think it's very easy to follow.

```py
# helper func to split nested list (NxN matrix) into 4 quadrants
def split_mat(mat):
    n = len(mat)
    s = math.ceil(n/2)
    up_left  = [mat[i][j] for i in range(0, s) for j in range(0, s)]
    up_right = [mat[i][j] for i in range(0, s) for j in range(s, n)]
    bt_left  = [mat[i][j] for i in range(s, n) for j in range(0, s)]
    bt_right = [mat[i][j] for i in range(s, n) for j in range(s, n)]
    return [up_left, up_right, bt_left, bt_right]

# then the averages you want to calculate becomes trivial
def avg_mat(mat):  
    quadrants = split_mat(mat)
    avgs = [sum(q)//len(q) for q in quadrants]
    return [[avgs[0], avgs[1]], [avgs[2], avgs[3]]]
```

```py
even_list = [
[1,6,5,6],
[2,5,6,8],
[7,2,8,1],
[4,4,7,3]]

print(avg_mat(even_list))
--------------------------------------------------
[[3, 6], [4, 4]]
```

```py
odd_list = [
[7,9,1],
[4,2,1],
[3,2,3]]

print(avg_mat(odd_list))
--------------------------------------------------
[[5, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit golfy, sorry, typing on phone means short names :). I take advantage of integer division to simply the logic, and use totals plus division over intermediate lists.

```
from itertools import product

def quad_avgs(M):
  sums = [[0,0],[0,0]]
  L, S, s = len(M), len(M) / 2, len(M) - len(M) / 2
  for r, c in product(range(L), repeat=2):
      sums[r / S][c / S] += M[r][c]
  return [[sums[r][c] / ([S, s][r] * [S, s][c]) for c in [0, 1]] for r in [0, 1]]
```